# How can I get the slc command to work on Ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have installed Strongloop using `npm install -g strongloop` on my Ubuntu 14.04 server. The `slc` command does not work. It says

`The program 'slc' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install heimdal-multidev`

How can I get it to run the Strongloop CLI instead of looking for this package? I have [added this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/loopbackjs/FUoYZLKgaTc/q0_S1zLPpyoJ) to my PATH and it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Other Strongloop commands, like `sl-build` work and `strongloop` is listed in `npm list -g`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the Node installation that optionally comes with a Digital Ocean Droplet installs to a different location that's not in `$PATH`. I'm pretty sure that was the issue. Anyways, I fixed it by spinning up a server without Node pre-installed and [followed this guide](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/install-node-js-loopback-and-strongops-on-digital-ocean/). Just use `npm install -g strongloop` instead of `strong-cli` because the latter has been deprecated.

Answer (score 7):

Ubuntu 14 with node.js 4.1.2

By default somehow slc is not created or not added to PATH.
I solved this problem by adding symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/bin/slc.js /usr/bin/slc
```

Answer (score 4):

A soft link named `slc` should have been created at /usr/local/bin which will point to `strongloop` binary.

Please verify if the following exists.

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/strongloop/bin/slc
```

If no, then `strongloop` did not get installed successfully, otherwise verify the existence of the **softlink** `slc` at `/usr/local/bin/`.

```
/usr/local/bin/slc -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/strongloop/bin/slc
```

If yes, then `/usr/local/bin` needs to be added to the `$PATH`, otherwise create the **softlink** and verify that `/usr/local/bin`in `$PATH`.

Comment: I actually _just_ fixed the issue. I'll post another answer. Don't delete yours. It may help people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.04 with node.js 4.4.2 (LTS) :

The installation of strongloop was done without any errors but slc was not added to the PATH. I solved this problem by adding the symlink:

```
    sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/strongloop/bin/slc.js /usr/bin/slc
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually i am not sure my case matches with yours but i want to share my experience. i got the same message anyway.

I realized that i had changed prefix of global packets before. Then i checked prefix with the following command.

$ npm config get prefix
/home/myUser/.node_modules_global

Then i added the path to PATH variable (but .profile, .bash_profile files will be better) in active command line window and problem solved.