# Strongloop deploy to Heroku doesn't work

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, loopbackjs, strongloop

Followed all the steps can't figure out how to get this done 
Keep getting 
bash: slc: command not found

Procfile
web: slc run

> 2015-03-26T02:43:13.998982+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   crashed to starting 2015-03-26T02:43:18.757072+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   Starting process with command `slc run`
>   2015-03-26T02:43:20.054559+00:00 app[web.1]: Detected 512 MB available
>   memory, 512 MB limit per process (WEB_MEMORY)
>   2015-03-26T02:43:20.054946+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: slc: command not
>   found 2015-03-26T02:43:20.054584+00:00 app[web.1]: Recommending
>   WEB_CONCURRENCY=1 2015-03-26T02:43:20.786104+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   Process exited with status 127 2015-03-26T02:43:20.807164+00:00
>   heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
>   2015-03-26T02:44:16.130969+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
>   host=salty-journey-3310.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=48c6c94a-22d7-4c5e-9a6c-2384c5d37cdc fwd="216.165.95.72"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2015-03-26T02:44:50.716616+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/worker-signin"
>   host=salty-journey-3310.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=e12abfd7-4d0a-4869-93b3-5139f8d4e34c fwd="216.165.95.72"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2015-03-26T02:46:07.463936+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/client-signup"
>   host=salty-journey-3310.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=be1015fc-a9b4-4b46-b858-b59ed1702d60 fwd="216.165.95.72"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2015-03-26T02:48:38.323367+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   crashed to starting 2015-03-26T02:48:44.211997+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   Starting process with command `slc run`
>   2015-03-26T02:48:46.005432+00:00 app[web.1]: Detected 512 MB available
>   memory, 512 MB limit per process (WEB_MEMORY)
>   2015-03-26T02:48:46.005458+00:00 app[web.1]: Recommending
>   WEB_CONCURRENCY=1 2015-03-26T02:48:46.024208+00:00 app[web.1]: bash:
>   slc: command not found 2015-03-26T02:48:46.871183+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   Process exited with status 127 2015-03-26T02:48:46.882329+00:00
>   heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
>   2015-03-26T02:55:07.351372+00:00 heroku[api]: Add strongloop:test
>   add-on by tejas.vj.bhatt@gmail.com 2015-03-26T02:55:07.351372+00:00
>   heroku[api]: Release v8 created by tejas.vj.bhatt@gmail.com
>   2015-03-26T02:55:07.460254+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   crashed to starting 2015-03-26T02:55:12.262442+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   Starting process with command `slc run`
>   2015-03-26T02:55:13.558424+00:00 app[web.1]: Detected 512 MB available
>   memory, 512 MB limit per process (WEB_MEMORY)
>   2015-03-26T02:55:13.558444+00:00 app[web.1]: Recommending
>   WEB_CONCURRENCY=1 2015-03-26T02:55:13.558648+00:00 app[web.1]: **bash:
>   slc: command not found** 2015-03-26T02:55:14.284209+00:00
>   heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
>   2015-03-26T02:55:14.278656+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
>   status 127 2015-03-26T02:57:35.737008+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy
>   b6cac37 by tejas.vj.bhatt@gmail.com 2015-03-26T02:57:35.737008+00:00
>   heroku[api]: Release v9 created by tejas.vj.bhatt@gmail.com
>   2015-03-26T02:57:35.974640+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   crashed to starting 2015-03-26T02:57:41.438704+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   Starting process with command `slc run`
>   2015-03-26T02:57:42.881097+00:00 app[web.1]: Detected 512 MB available
>   memory, 512 MB limit per process (WEB_MEMORY)
>   2015-03-26T02:57:42.881117+00:00 app[web.1]: Recommending
>   WEB_CONCURRENCY=1 2015-03-26T02:57:42.881843+00:00 app[web.1]: bash:
>   slc: command not found 2015-03-26T02:57:43.606052+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   Process exited with status 127 2015-03-26T02:57:43.633805+00:00
>   heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
>   2015-03-26T02:58:01.953397+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
>   host=salty-journey-3310.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=5b405b2b-3e81-4140-8ed6-205868383854 fwd="216.165.95.72"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

Comment: Take a look on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222932/how-can-i-get-the-slc-command-to-work-on-ubuntu#answer-29224343

Comment: not able to figure out why, it works fine on my local
how can i follow the steps for deploying to heroku

Comment: I managed to run this by using `Procfile web: node server/server.js`

Answer (score 3):

I believe your best bet is to remove the buildpack and edit your Procfile to be `web: node .`.

Why? Strongloop-specific tooling is no longer being maintained since being purchased by IBM. Loopback itself is being maintained, and in fact the [loopback-cli](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-cli) project specifically mentions that it "supersedes" strongloop's "older slc tool."

Note that loopback-cli should not be necessary to run the heroku server.

Answer (score 0):

I think I saw this error when I didn't create the app with the strongloop buildpack.  I'm assuming you're following the [strongloop heroku article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/strongloop), did you get all the way through it?

I missed this step:

```
heroku apps:create --buildpack https://github.com/strongloop/strongloop-buildpacks.git
```

Comment: Nope I couldn't, I will checkout the above, I was able to deploy to Digital ocean as it gives a good control over the server. Not sure if heroku does that too